# Can I see in Google Chrome a fluid layout web page in the same way as it is shown in a mobile web browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, webkit, mobile-safari

My question assumes I know about the device's resolution and dpi and my monitor resolution and dpi. Also, the web page layout is fluid (everything expressed in percentages of em, as per w3c recommendations).
For example, let's say that in the mobile device I have a screen of 480x320 and a dpi of 192. My monitor has a dpi of 96, does that mean that I should see the same thing as in the mobile browser if I set my desktop's Chrome's dimensions at 960x640? If not, what factors should I account for?

Answer (score 2):

No. You will see the same thing as you will see on the phone if you set chrome's dimensions at 480x320. Pixels are the same no matter whether you are viewing them on a phone, or on a desktop computer.

The DPI figure just tells you the RESOLUTION of the device. e.g. your computer has 96 pixels per inch and your phone has 192. Therefore, 480*320 will take up a bigger physical area on your computer than on your phone screen, although the output will (should be*) exactly the same.

*If you're using any scripts/code which checks for a Useragent and varies the output depending on whether it is a phone/browser/netbook/whatever then you'll need to take this into account. You can get chrome plugins which "spoof" Useragents, allowing you to look at a site as if you are a mobile device. If you're just literally using clever CSS and fluid layouts however you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the User-Agent string and emulate different mobile resolutions in the Chrome developer tools.

Open the developer tools with `F12`, click the gear icon in the lower right corner and open the **User agent** tab.

There's a difference between hardware pixels and normalized optical pixels, but it's complicated matter. I suggest reading more about it on [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) or [A list apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/a-pixel-identity-crisis/).

Comment: And don't forget to turn it off when done. (I was wondering for 5 seconds why the mobile version of SO loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, 
Simply Hit `Ctrl++` you will see the difference, to zoom out use `Ctrl--`,
to Come to original State press `Ctrl+0`.
 you can also `Resize the window manually`, this will change the fluid layout too.